JavaScript - Array contains HTMLDivElements instead of textContent from the elements (numbers)
I am working on a vanilla JavaScript bingo game. I create my bingo card element, then create a grid. I create 5 arrays of 5 randomized numbers each. Then for each number in each array, I create a div element, add a class of 'marker' to the element, stick in the randomized number as the textContent, and append the element to the HTML. Creating the card works fine. I have also set up to mark the spaces on the cards. When a space is marked I add a class of 'marked' to it.
Now I am trying to return an array of the marked spaces (this is the first part of a method to check if the person has an actual bingo). I grab all of the card spaces using querySelectorAll(".marker"). I then run an Array.from filter method to pull out the spaces that contain the 'marked' class. Then I assign the textContent (a number) from that space (the div element) to a variable and return that variable. I have a console.log to tell me what the textContent is before I return it. When the filtering is done, I do a console.log of the array that is supposed to contain the values from the textContents of all the elements.
The problem is that instead of showing the numbers from the spaces, the final console log reads as follows:
The marked spaces are: [object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement]
The console log inside the filter shows the actual number that is the textContent, and that is what I'm returning in the filter method. So why is the array I'm saving those numbers to showing each as an HTMLDivElement instead of string/number like the inner console log?


const bingoCard = () => {
  const bingoCardSpace = document.getElementById('bingo-card');
  const cardSheet = document.createElement("main");
  cardSheet.classList.add('inline-block', 'mx-auto', 'min-w-fit', 'border-8', 'bg-[#4bb2d3]', 'border-[#4bb2de]');
  bingoCardSpace.appendChild(cardSheet);

  const cardHeader = document.createElement('header');
  cardHeader.classList.add('flex', 'rounded-xl', 'bg-[#345995ff]');
  cardSheet.appendChild(cardHeader);

  const cardLetters = ['B', 'I', 'N', 'G', 'O'];

  for (let i = 0; i < cardLetters.length; i++) {
    const headerCell = document.createElement('div');
    headerCell.textContent = cardLetters[i];
    headerCell.classList.add('w-28', 'h-28', 'font-chewy', 'text-7xl', 'flex', 'justify-center', 'items-center', 'bg-[#f5f5f4ff]', 'rounded-full', 'mx-2', 'my-2');
    if (i != cardLetters.length - 1) headerCell.classList.add('mr-2');
    cardHeader.appendChild(headerCell);
  }

  const card = document.createElement("div");
  card.setAttribute("id", "card");
  card.classList.add('inline-grid', 'grid-rows-5', 'grid-flow-col', 'bg-[#4bb2de]');
  cardSheet.appendChild(card);

  let cardNumbers = [];
  cardNumbers = createCardArrays();
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      const cardCell = document.createElement("div");
      let cardCellNumber = cardNumbers[i][j];
      if (i === 2 && j === 2) {
        cardCell.textContent = "FREE";
      } else {
        cardCell.textContent = cardCellNumber;
      }
      cardCell.classList.add('marker', 'w-28', 'h-28', 'font-lato', 'text-5xl', 'flex', 'justify-center', 'items-center', 'bg-[#f5f5f4ff]', 'rounded-full', 'mx-2', 'my-2', cardCellNumber);
      card.appendChild(cardCell);
    }
  }
  listenForMarkingSpaces();
}

function createCardArrays() {
  const cardNumbers = new Array(5);
  let max, min;
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cardNumbers[i] = [];
    max = 15 * (i + 1);
    min = max - 14;
    cardNumbers[i] = generateRandomNumbers(5, min, max);
  }
  return cardNumbers;
}

function generateRandomNumbers(count, min, max) {
  let uniqueNumbers = new Set();
  while (uniqueNumbers.size < count) {
    uniqueNumbers.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
  }
  const uniqueNumbersArray = [...uniqueNumbers];
  return uniqueNumbersArray;
}

const bingoBalls = () => {
  const ballArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 75; i++) {
    ballArray.push(i);
  }
  return ballArray;
}

let bingoBallsNotDrawn = bingoBalls();
let bingoBallsDrawn = [];

const drawBingoBall = () => {
  let ballDrawn = 0;
  while (bingoBallsNotDrawn.indexOf(ballDrawn) === -1) {
    ballDrawn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) + 1;
  }
  bingoBallsNotDrawn = bingoBallsNotDrawn.filter(ball => ball !== ballDrawn);
  console.log('bingoBallsNotDrawn now has ' + bingoBallsNotDrawn.length + ' balls in it');
  if (ballDrawn >= 61) ballDrawn = 'O-' + ballDrawn;
  else if (ballDrawn >= 46) ballDrawn = 'G-' + ballDrawn;
  else if (ballDrawn >= 31) ballDrawn = 'N-' + ballDrawn;
  else if (ballDrawn >= 16) ballDrawn = 'I-' + ballDrawn;
  else ballDrawn = 'B-' + ballDrawn;
  bingoBallsDrawn.push(ballDrawn);
  showBallDrawnOnScreen(ballDrawn);
  addBallToBallsDrawnList(ballDrawn);
  console.log('bingoBallsDrawn now has ' + bingoBallsDrawn);
  console.log('bingoBallsNotDrawn: ' + bingoBallsNotDrawn);
}

const showBallDrawnOnScreen = (ballDrawn) => {
  const currentBall = document.getElementById('currentBall');
  currentBall.textContent = "";
  const currentBallNumber = document.createTextNode(ballDrawn);
  currentBall.appendChild(currentBallNumber);
}

const addBallToBallsDrawnList = (ballDrawn) => {
  const ballList = document.getElementById("accordion-content");
  const listedBall = document.createElement("div");
  listedBall.textContent = ballDrawn;
  listedBall.classList.add('text-4xl', 'text-center', 'py-2', 'px-4', 'border-r-2', 'border-l-2', 'border-b-2', 'border-[#714BDE]', 'text-[#714BDE]');
  ballList.appendChild(listedBall);
}

const listenForMarkingSpaces = () => {
  const spaces = document.querySelectorAll(".marker");
  spaces.forEach((space) => {
    space.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
      space.classList.toggle('bg-[#f5f5f4ff]');
      space.classList.toggle('bg-[#26c485ff]');
      space.classList.toggle('marked');
    });
  });
}

const toggleAccordion = () => {
  document.getElementById('accordion-content').classList.toggle("hidden");
  document.getElementById('arrow-icon').classList.toggle("rotate-180");
}

const startNewGame = () => {
  const ballList = document.getElementById("accordion-content");
  ballList.innerHTML = '';
  const currentBall = document.getElementById('currentBall');
  currentBall.textContent = '';
  const spaces = document.querySelectorAll(".marker");
  spaces.forEach((space) => {
    space.classList.remove('bg-[#f5f5f4ff]');
    space.classList.remove('bg-[#26c485ff]');
    space.classList.remove('marked');
    space.classList.add('bg-[#f5f5f4ff]');
  });
}

const checkIfMarksAreCorrect = () => {
  const spaces = document.querySelectorAll(".marker");
  const markedSpaces = Array.from(spaces).filter((space) => {
    if (space.classList.contains('marked')) {
      console.log(space.textContent);
      spaceNumber = space.textContent;
      return spaceNumber;
    }
  });
  console.log('The marked spaces are: ' + markedSpaces);
}
<div class="flex">
  <div class="w-3/4 h-100lvh flex flex-col border-r border-black-500" id="bingo-card">
    <div class="flex justify-center">
      <button class="rounded-full text-4xl m-4 py-2 px-4 border-2 border-[#714BDE] text-[#714BDE] hover:bg-[#714BDE] hover:text-gray-100 focus:outline-none" onclick="startNewGame()">New game</button>
      <button class="rounded-full text-4xl m-4 py-2 px-4 border-2 border-[#714BDE] text-[#714BDE] hover:bg-[#714BDE] hover:text-gray-100 focus:outline-none" onclick="bingoCard()">Click to create card</button>
      <button class="rounded-full text-4xl m-4 py-2 px-4 border-2 border-[#714BDE] text-[#714BDE] hover:bg-[#714BDE] hover:text-gray-100 focus:outline-none" onclick="drawBingoBall()">Click to draw ball</button>
      <button class="rounded-full text-4xl m-4 py-2 px-4 border-2 border-[#714BDE] text-[#714BDE] hover:bg-[#714BDE] hover:text-gray-100 focus:outline-none" onclick="checkIfMarksAreCorrect()">Click to check card</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-1/5">
    <div class="flex mt-4 text-[#714BDE] font-bold justify-center text-4xl">
      Current ball: <span id="currentBall" class="ml-4 text-[#A14BDE]"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="overflow-hidden" onclick="toggleAccordion()">
      <div class="flex text-4xl justify-center mx-4 mt-4 py-2 px-4 border-2 border-[#714BDE] text-[#714BDE]">
        Balls drawn
        <span class="transform transition-transform" id="arrow-icon">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
                            stroke="currentColor" class="size-12">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="m19.5 8.25-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
      </div>
      <div class="px-4 hidden" id="accordion-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




"...the array I'm saving those numbers..." You are not saving the numbers, the value you return from the .filter() callback, tells .filter() if it should KEEP the original array content or not. It is not mapping the array values to something new, it is filtering out some of the array entries and keep the others.

.filter is not .map

It would be easier to use qsa again to get markedSpaces - .marker.marked

Please add CSS to the snippet I made you

Why remove and add the same class? space.classList.remove('bg-[#f5f5f4ff]'); space.classList.add('bg-[#f5f5f4ff]');

Only some of the spaces have #f5f5f4ff as their bg color, so I need to add it to the other spaces at that point in the code. My concern was that if I just do the .add, the spaces that already have that will have two entries of 'bg-[#f5f5f4ff] in their class list, then in the third game they'll have three, then four. I don't want to build up a list of the same class entry on an element. But since you mention it, I will test to see if that will actually happen.

The problem is happening in the function "checkIfMarksAreCorrect". When you use the filter method, you're managing what data will be returned if it matches the condition. In this case if the element has "marked" in the class list. It doesn't manipulate how the data gets returned. You need to use map() for this. Try using this code:
const checkIfMarksAreCorrect = () => {
    const spaces = document.querySelectorAll(".marker");
    const markedSpaces = Array.from(spaces)
        .filter((space) => space.classList.contains('marked'))
        .map((markedSpace) => markedSpace.textContent.trim());

        console.log('The marked spaces are: ' + markedSpaces);
};

See if that works.

@apex2022 Please let me know if this solution fixes your problem.

It did finally work. Thank you.

You're welcome. Can you please select this as the correct answer?
